# Factorization $\cos(z) - \sin(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

How do I find the product expansion of $\cos z - \sin z$

We have $\cos z = \sin z$ iff $z = \pi/4 + k \pi$ where $k$ is an integer.  The sequence

$\sum (r/(|\pi/4 + k \pi|)^2$ converges

For some sequence of integers $p_n$, $e^{g(z)} \prod_{n \in {\bf Z}} E_{p_n}({z \over \pi/4 + n \pi})) = \cos z - \sin z$ where $E_{p_n}$ is the Weierstrass factor.

and ${p_n} $ = the constant sequence 1 makes the product converge.  However unlike the product for sin we don't have cancellation

From Hadamard we have that $g(z)$ is of the form $az + b$ if we use the constant sequence 1 for the p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cos(z) - \sin(z) = - \sqrt{2}\; \sin(z - \pi/4)$, then use the infinite product  formula for the sine.